# MATLAB use of bracket, semicolon and single quotes with matrix

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix

I have this piece of code in MATLAB:

```
scaling = 1;
rho = scaling * (0:1 / (int_len / 2):1);
rho = [rho'; rho(end - 1:-1:2)'];
```

and actually I have to translate it to Python. I don't know MATLAB and I couldn't figure out what this code is doing. The value of int_len in this case is not important for my doubt, it's a multiplication from two previous values.

For what I understood, in the second line, rho will be and array from 0 to 1 with a step of 1 / (int_len / 2). (suppose the result of the step is 0.2, I would have `[0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1]`)

But the third line, I got a little bit confusing. Is it adding a row to rho to create a 2D matrix? I have to translate this to Python and I'm actually still learning Python and Numpy. So if I'm really adding a new row, it's just use the numpy.vstack() or is there another way to do this?

Comment: FYI: That code works in [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), which is free.  For figuring out basic Matlab code like this, Octave is great.

Comment: Actually it is a good idea to test some other stuff too! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation of the second line is correct. In the third line, the 1-by-N row vector `rho` is first transposed with `'`(**note:** this should really be [`.'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html)) to create an N-by-1 column vector. This is [vertically concatenated](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) (using `[...; ...]`) with another column vector created by [indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) `rho` in reverse from one less than the [end](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html) to the second element and transposing it with `'`.

In short, it creates a column vector with the values of `rho` followed by the reversed values (not counting the end points). For your example data, `rho` would end up like this:

```
rho = [0; 0.2; 0.4; 0.6; 0.8; 1; 0.8; 0.6; 0.4; 0.2]
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it makes sense the code. And just to make it clear for me, why to transpose should be .' instead of ' ? I'm asking this because actually in this MATLAB code I have I already seen a lot of this . followed by other operations, like A .* B or A./ B for example. What does this really mean?

Comment: @BarbaAlGhul: `.'` is the [transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) operator, which will transpose a matrix or vector but leave the contents unchanged. `'` is the [complex conjugate transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) operator. If the matrix or vector contains no complex elements, these two operators give the same result, but if complex elements *are* present, they give different results. For clarity, reshaping of a matrix or vector should only ever use `.'`. It's just poor practice to use `'` by default, but most do.